# weak implies strong convergence in $l^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I want to prove Schur theorem stating that every weak convergent sequence in $l^1$ is strongly convergent. If we let $(x_n)_n=(x^i_n)\in l^1$, then $(x_n)_n$ converge weakly to $x$ if for any $y \in l^\infty$ we have $$(x_n-x,y)_{l^1\times l^\infty}\rightarrow 0.$$
Now, let $y=sing(x_n-x)$, we obtain  $$(x_n-x,x_n-x)_{l^1\times l^\infty}=||x_n-x||_{l^1}\rightarrow 0.$$
I this passage is correct?.
Thank you.

Comment: You cannot make $y$ dependent on $n$. It has to be a fixed vectrro in the definition of weak convergence.

Comment: Two hints: Banach-Steinhaus shows that $||x_n||_1$ is bounded; also $e_n-(0,0,\dots,0,1,0,0,\dots)\in\ell^\infty$.

Comment: You must use some specific properties of $l^1$ & its dual space $(l^1)^*=l^{\infty}$ because Shur's result does not apply to $every$ Banach space  & its dual.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I still don't understand why this choice of $y$ is impossible? either it is 1 or -1 which cleaely makes since

Comment: Think about the case of weak convergence in $\ell^2$: If $e_n=(0,\ldots,0, 1, 0,\ldots)\in \ell^2$, then $e_n\to 0$ weakly, but the pairing with it's dual $\ell^2$ would give, with your choice of $y$, that the sequence $1, 1, 1, \ldots, 1, 1, \ldots$ converges to 0.